# rsync "File name too long (36)" error for filenames with UTF-8 characters

Tags: linux, rsync, filenames, ext4, utf-8

Trying to copy files from an NTFS-formatted HDD to an EXT4-formatted HDD, `rsync` fails to copy some of them having relatively long file names consisting of Asian (UTF-8) characters.

For example, there's a file with the name:

`动态网自由门 天安門 天安门 法輪功 李洪志 Free Tibet 六四天安門事件 The Tiananmen Square protests of 1989 天安門大屠殺 The Tiananmen Square Massacre 反右派鬥爭 The Anti-Rightist Struggle 大躍進政策 The Great Leap Forward 文化大革命.gif`

which is inside a not so short directory path, and `rsync`, even with `-s` and `--iconv=utf8` fails to copy them, saying, for example:

```
sending incremental file list

rsync: [generator] recv_generator: failed to stat "/path/to/file/\#345\#212\#250\#346\#200\#201\#347\#275\#221\#350\#207\#252\#347\#224\#261\#351\#227\#250 \#345\#244\#251\#345\#256\#211\#351\#226\#200 \#345\#244\#251\#345\#256\#211\#351\#227\#250 \#346\#263\#225\#350\#274\#252\#345\#212\#237 \#346\#235\#216\#346\#264\#252\#345\#277\#227 Free Tibet \#345\#205\#255\#345\#233\#233\#345\#244\#251\#345\#256\#211\#351\#226\#200\#344\#272\#213\#344\#273\#266 The Tiananmen Square protests of 1989 \#345\#244\#251\#345\#256\#211\#351\#226\#200\#345\#244\#247\#345\#261\#240\#346\#256\#272 The Tiananmen Square Massacre \#345\#217\#215\#345\#217\#263\#346\#264\#276\#351\#254\#245\#347\#210\#255 The Anti-Rightist Struggle \#345\#244\#247\#350\#272\#215\#351\#200\#262\#346\#224\#277\#347\#255\#226 The Great Leap Forward \#346\#226\#207\#345\#214\#226\#345\#244\#247\#351\#235\#251\#345\#221\#275.gif": File name too long (36)
```

Is there any fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file name length limit in NTFS is *255 UTF-16 [code units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Mapping_and_encodings)* (CU). `动态网自由门 天安門 天安门 法輪功 李洪志 Free Tibet 六四天安門事件 The Tiananmen Square protests of 1989 天安門大屠殺 The Tiananmen Square Massacre 反右派鬥爭 The Anti-Rightist Struggle 大躍進政策 The Great Leap Forward 文化大革命.gif` is a **188-CU string in UTF-16**, but is encoded in **280 CUs in UTF-8** which obviously exceeded the limit in ext4 (*255 UTF-8 CUs*)

UTF-8 encodes code points U+0800 to U+FFFF in 3 bytes, therefore high code points such as Chinese characters and many emojis will need more bytes to encode than UTF-16, and the resulting string will be longer

One solution if you want to stick with native Linux file systems is to use [ReiserFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS) whose limit is 4032 bytes, i.e. **4032 UTF-8 CUs**, if you want to preserve the names. Alternatively use [Reiser4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiser4) which is the successor to ReiserFS. Its limit is only 3976 bytes but still far more than enough. Otherwise you have no other option but truncate the names

For non-Linux file systems there are many more options. All Windows file systems obviously work because they all work in UTF-16. NTFS and exFAT both have excellent kernel drivers in Linux for a long time so they're also a good choice. Another possible answer is [HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) which also uses UTF-16, but it's a terrible FS so just stay away from that

See [To what extent does Linux support file names longer than 255 bytes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/619625/44425)

---

You can use tools such as https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ to check the encoded bytes in various encodings. The above string in UTF-16 is

```
52A8 6001 7F51 81EA 7531 95E8 0020 5929 5B89 9580 0020 5929 5B89 95E8 0020 6CD5
8F2A 529F 0020 674E 6D2A 5FD7 0020 0046 0072 0065 0065 0020 0054 0069 0062 0065
0074 0020 516D 56DB 5929 5B89 9580 4E8B 4EF6 0020 0054 0068 0065 0020 0054 0069
0061 006E 0061 006E 006D 0065 006E 0020 0053 0071 0075 0061 0072 0065 0020 0070
0072 006F 0074 0065 0073 0074 0073 0020 006F 0066 0020 0031 0039 0038 0039 0020
5929 5B89 9580 5927 5C60 6BBA 0020 0054 0068 0065 0020 0054 0069 0061 006E 0061
006E 006D 0065 006E 0020 0053 0071 0075 0061 0072 0065 0020 004D 0061 0073 0073
0061 0063 0072 0065 0020 53CD 53F3 6D3E 9B25 722D 0020 0054 0068 0065 0020 0041
006E 0074 0069 002D 0052 0069 0067 0068 0074 0069 0073 0074 0020 0053 0074 0072
0075 0067 0067 006C 0065 0020 5927 8E8D 9032 653F 7B56 0020 0054 0068 0065 0020
0047 0072 0065 0061 0074 0020 004C 0065 0061 0070 0020 0046 006F 0072 0077 0061
0072 0064 0020 6587 5316 5927 9769 547D 002E 0067 0069 0066
```

In UTF-8 it's

```
E5 8A A8 E6 80 81 E7 BD 91 E8 87 AA E7 94 B1 E9 97 A8 20 E5 A4 A9 E5 AE 89 E9
96 80 20 E5 A4 A9 E5 AE 89 E9 97 A8 20 E6 B3 95 E8 BC AA E5 8A 9F 20 E6 9D 8E
E6 B4 AA E5 BF 97 20 46 72 65 65 20 54 69 62 65 74 20 E5 85 AD E5 9B 9B E5 A4
A9 E5 AE 89 E9 96 80 E4 BA 8B E4 BB B6 20 54 68 65 20 54 69 61 6E 61 6E 6D 65
6E 20 53 71 75 61 72 65 20 70 72 6F 74 65 73 74 73 20 6F 66 20 31 39 38 39 20
E5 A4 A9 E5 AE 89 E9 96 80 E5 A4 A7 E5 B1 A0 E6 AE BA 20 54 68 65 20 54 69 61
6E 61 6E 6D 65 6E 20 53 71 75 61 72 65 20 4D 61 73 73 61 63 72 65 20 E5 8F 8D
E5 8F B3 E6 B4 BE E9 AC A5 E7 88 AD 20 54 68 65 20 41 6E 74 69 2D 52 69 67 68
74 69 73 74 20 53 74 72 75 67 67 6C 65 20 E5 A4 A7 E8 BA 8D E9 80 B2 E6 94 BF
E7 AD 96 20 54 68 65 20 47 72 65 61 74 20 4C 65 61 70 20 46 6F 72 77 61 72 64
20 E6 96 87 E5 8C 96 E5 A4 A7 E9 9D A9 E5 91 BD 2E 67 69 66
```

Comment: What is the `\#345\#212\#250` (an example) representation of the characters called?

Comment: @SeppA `动` is encoded as `E5 8A A8` in UTF-8 which is `345 212 250` in octal

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned over
[on Unix StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50441082/165358),
the maximum filename in an ext4 system is 255 bytes.
Note also that a non-ASCII character in UTF8 takes at least 2 bytes.

It seems to me that you have exceeded this limit.